# Scrapy: How do I modify a URL from Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I read that I can use process_links as a callback but the rule already has my parse_item callback so I can't specify another one before that, right?

I wrote a middleware but scrapy stopped doing anything after I enabled it. I tried the following as a test.

```
class UrlModifyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        m_url = 'http://checkip.dyndns.org/'
        return request.replace(url = m_url)
```

Comment: You can have both `process_links` and `callback` arguments in your `Rule` instance. `process_links` should be a callable, either an independant function or the name of a spider method. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106294/rewrite-scrapy-urls-before-sending-the-request

Comment: I just realized that my Middleware was actually working. It just kept going on in an infinite loop.