# modifying urls before sending for fetching in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to parse sitemap and find out all urls from sitemap and then appending some word to all urls and then I want to check response code of all modified urls.

for this task I decided to use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) because it have luxury to crawl sitemaps. its given in scarpy's [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/topics/spiders.html#built-in-spiders-reference)

with the help of this documentation I created my spider. but I want to change urls before sending for fetching. so for this I tried to take help from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106294/rewrite-scrapy-urls-before-sending-the-request). this link suggested my to use `rules` and implement `process_requests()`. but I am not able to make use of these. I tired little bit that I have commented. could anyone help me write exact code for commented lines or any other ways to do this task in scrapy?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml']
    #sitemap_rules = [some_rules, process_request='process_request')]

    #def process_request(self, request, spider):
    #   modified_url=orginal_url_from_sitemap + 'myword'
    #   return request.replace(url = modified_url)        

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.status, response.url
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the request_scheduled signal to a function and do what you want in the function. For example

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        spider = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.request_scheduled, signals.request_scheduled)

    def request_scheduled(self, request, spider):
        modified_url = orginal_url_from_sitemap + 'myword'
        request.url = modified_url
```

Comment: Nope, `request.url` cannot be modified - you need to use `.replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

`SitemapSpider` has [`sitemap_filter` method.](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.6.0/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py#L34-L40)
You can override it to implement required functionality.

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):

    ...
        def sitemap_filter(self, entries):

            for entry in entries:
                entry["loc"] = entry["loc"] + myword
                yield entry
```

Each of that `entry` objects are dicts with structure like this:

```
<class 'dict'>:
 {'loc': 'https://example.com/',
  'lastmod': '2019-01-04T08:09:23+00:00',
  'changefreq': 'weekly',
  'priority': '0.8'}
```

**Important note!**. `SitemapSpider.sitemap_filter` method appeared on scrapy 1.6.0  released on Jan 2019 [1.6.0 release notes - new extensibility features section](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#new-extensibility-features)

Answer (score 0):

I've just facet this. Apparently you can't really use `process_requests` because sitemap rules in `SitemapSpider` are different from `Rule` objects in `CrawlSpider` - only the latter can have this argument.

After examining [the code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py) it looks like this can be avoided by manually overriding part of `SitemapSpider` implementation:

```
class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    sitemap_urls = ['...']
    sitemap_rules = [('/', 'parse')]

    def start_requests(self):
        # override to call custom_parse_sitemap instead of _parse_sitemap
        for url in self.sitemap_urls:
            yield Request(url, self.custom_parse_sitemap)

    def custom_parse_sitemap(self, response):
        # modify requests marked to be called with parse callback
        for request in super()._parse_sitemap(response):
            if request.callback == self.parse:
                yield self.modify_request(request)
            else:
                yield request

    def modify_request(self, request):
        return request.replace(
            # ...
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # ...
```